# UIView animation animates but immediately moves back to original position

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

This is written in Swift 2 in Xcode 7.

I have a `UIView`, which originally is set to be below the screen. Upon being triggered, it should slide up from the bottom of screen. This is the code for the animation:

```
func durationView(sender: UIButton){
    let heightOffset = self.durationNotificationContainerView.frame.height

    self.durationNotificationContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {self.durationNotificationContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(self.durationNotificationContainerView.frame.origin.x, self.durationNotificationContainerView.frame.origin.y + heightOffset, self.durationNotificationContainerView.frame.width, self.durationNotificationContainerView.frame.height)})
}
```

What happens right now is when I press the `UIButton` that triggers this view, it slides up and then immediately back down (to outside of the screen). I should also point out that in my storyboard I have some views added manually with AutoLayout constraints, so I don't know if that's what is messing up my animation.

Comment: yes, that causes the issue, you must not set the frame property when using auto layout  - you have to connect the layoutconstrains as outlets and manipulate them.

Comment: but that view that is being animated doesn't have any constraints. if I had created everything programmatically with `CGRectMake` would it have been fine?

Comment: If your view doesn't have any constraints, setting the frame is fine. Giving this a quick try.

Comment: Yea.. Just wrote a little app that moves a view on button press using your function, and there are no issues. Works beautifully setting the frame as long as you don't have any constraints on it. Double check.

Comment: actually your code works for me, but the view does not go up but down because you are adding a value to the Y. It Does not go back on its initial place

Answer (score 0):

In Autolayout, constraints need to be changed and updated in the the animation as seen below:

```
- (IBAction)moveAction:(id)sender {
    self.spaceConstraint.constant += 220;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
         [self.imageView layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```